Lower bound for mean value of Sobolev function
Assume that for a Sobolev function $f\in W^{2,p}(E)$, for some $p>1$ and $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, that the weak derivative $\nabla f$ is essentially bounded in $E$ and that we already know that $|\nabla f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for a.e. $x \in B_R(y)\subset E$. Does it then also follows that the mean value satisfies
$$\Bigg|\frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}\nabla f(y)\,\mathrm dy\bigg| \geq \frac{1}{2}?$$
Heuristically this should hold true as a Sobolev function is not allowed to "jump", however I am unable to verify it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
Edit: I changed the assumption to $W^{2,p}(E)$ rather than $W^{1,p}(E)$.

I don't think there is a problem as $\nabla f$ is already assumed to be a measurable function. This is what the definition of $W^{1,p}$ starts with.

@Liding Yao The problem is that the absolute value is outside the integral I think ...

No, this is false, the function is not allowed to jump but its derivative can. Take for example $f(x) = |x|$ on a bounded domain. Then $|\nabla f| = 1$ but for any ball $B$ centered at $0$
$$
\int_B \nabla f = \int_B\frac{x}{|x|}\,\mathrm d x = 0.
$$

Thanks for your answer! However, I changed my assumption to a $W^{2,p}(E)$ function instead of $W^{1,p}(E)$ from before, so let us assume that u is twice weakly differentiable. Now, the first weak derivative should not be allowed to "jump", and thus the claimed lower bound for the mean value shold hold true, or am I mistaken? Thanks again and sorry for the change!

It would be better to ask another question then. This is the way the site works I think.
